# Python's dynaconf does not merge multi-file settings correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, configuration

I am using [dynaconf](https://www.dynaconf.com/configuration/) to manage my programs' settings. But i often need to switch between debugging and regular run profile.

In `default.yaml` I have:

```yaml
SETTINGS:
   RUN_WITH_SEED: false
   SEED: 42

   COLORS: ['red', 'white']
```

And in my `debug.yaml` I have only:

```yaml
SETTINGS:
   RUN_WITH_SEED: true
```

However, when I load the debug after the default it also removes the untouched settings. I really want to avoid writing all settings again because most are unchanged and there are quite a few.

This is how I load them:

```py
config_files = ['config/default.yaml', 'config/.secrets.yaml', 'config/debug.yaml']


config = Dynaconf(
        envvar_prefix="DYNACONF",
        settings_files=config_files,
)

print(config.SETTINGS.COLORS)
```

Yields:

```
"'DynaBox' object has no attribute 'colors'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mkashwin](https://github.com/dynaconf/dynaconf/issues/863) helped me and there are 2 options, one which i prefer:

```
config = Dynaconf(
envvar_prefix="DYNACONF",
settings_files=config_files,
merge_enabled=True
)
```

And second, by adding `DYNACONF_MERGE: true` to the end on the `YAML` we get the same behavior.

Comment: A brief gotcha - this won't always work with Dynaconf (as of 3.2.3), specifically not for nested values: "The dynaconf_merge and @merge functionalities work only for the first level keys, it will not merge subdicts or nested lists (yet)."